# Taylor series problem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> Find and state the convergence properties of the Taylor series for the
>   following:
>
> a.) $f(z)=z^3\sin 3z$ around $z_0=0$
>
> b.) $f(z)= \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ around $z_0=0$

I know that the Taylor/Maclaurian series for $\sin 3z = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} (3z)^{2n+1}$ but for $z^3$ I can just keep taking the derivative, thus:

$f(0)=z^3,\ f'(0)=3z^2,\ f''(0)=6z,\ f'''(0)=6,\ f''''(0)=0$, but how can I incorporated this into my taylor series of $\sin 3z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The powers step inside: $z^3 \sin 3z=z^3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} 3^{2n+1} z^{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^n 3^{2n+1} }{(2n+1)!} z^{2n+4}$.

As for the other one, leave the numerator $z$ alone for a moment, and consider $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ this is *almost* the derivative of a well known power series. Once you figure it out, all you have to do is multiply by the $z$ from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! Seems so obviosus now.

Comment: Michael, how can I do this problem:

$cosz$ around $z_0=\pi/4$?

Comment: we know that $\cos z=\cos [(z-\frac{\pi}{4})+\frac{\pi}{4}]$. use the trigonometric identity of cosine of addition, and use the known Taylor series for $\sin$ and $\cos$.